# How to require css file using NPM and Meteor?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, npm, browserify

I want to add the react-date-picker (https://github.com/zippyui/react-date-picker). It says that I need to add the lines

```
require('react-date-picker/index.css');
var DatePicker = require('react-date-picker');
```

And using meteorhacks:npm and browserify, I have the module working.

/server/declarations.js

```
DatePicker = Meteor.npmRequire('react-date-picker');
```

/lib/app.browserify.js

```
DatePicker = require('react-date-picker');
```

But how can I get the CSS file that styles the module to work? I don't know where to put the `require('react-date-picker/index.css')` without throwing a syntax error. And I can't assign it to a variable, so what do I do?

Answer (score 5):

When Meteor 1.3.2 comes out, you will be able to do, in `foo.js`:

`import "npm-package-name/path/to/style.css";`

If you are < 1.3.2, the workaround is to create a package in `packages/my-asset-imports` like this:

https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/9ea1ba440cb999af9c95

Answer (score 0):

You don't need meteorhacks:npm!

Update your app to Meteor 1.3 Beta by following this guide: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5788

Then read here how to use the new features: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.3/packages/modules/README.md

This fully solves your issue.

Comment: I don't see how that solves this issue really? The OP wants to access a CSS file that is included in an NPM module. Currently (also in Meteor 1.3) the only way to do that is by adding the CSS file as @import '../node_modules/react-date-picker/index.css' (or something similar) in the CSS file in your app.